# Can we translate the Page URLs using Language Copy in AEM?

Tags: aem

We are planning to use the Language copy feature for the translation of our English content and have done a small POC using Microsoft trial translator.

We noticed that the created language copy has the URL structure in the English language itself. Let's say if we create a language copy of `/content/site/en/test-page`, it will create it as `/content/site/es/test-page`, which is correct but the URL of the Spanish page would be in English. But we want to translate the URL as well for the Spanish language copy. So it should be `/content/site/en/página de prueba` (in Spanish)

Is it achievable to translate the URL of the page using language copy? what are the different options here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AEM needs pages to have the same path (and name) after the language node in order to see that this is / should be a language copy. So changing the node name is not an option in your case. In addition to that, changing a page name will be regarded as a move event in AEM and in the end, AEM will not be able to connect your language copies any more.

You can change the alias instead, which is in the page properties in the "Advanced" tab (see https://docs.adobe.com/content/help/en/experience-manager-65/authoring/authoring/editing-page-properties.html for further explanations). If you have spanish aliases for all spanish pages, then your URLs will be using those spanish aliases which is exactly what you would like to have, I guess...

HTH,
OliG

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Sling:alias seems to be working in this condition. But how can we put a redirect for all Spanish pages to go to their alias URLs? I have asked this question here-  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61395667/how-to-redirect-the-pages-to-their-alias-urls-in-aem   @Oliver Gebert