# How to redirect the pages to their alias URLs in AEM?

Tags: aem

We are planning to use `sling:alias` property for the translated pages through language copy so that the translated pages could be accessible through the translated URLs.

For e.g.

English page- `/content/site/en/test-page`

Language copy- `/content/site/es/test-page` - It has the property sling:alias (página de prueba)

Alias URL- `/content/site/es/página de prueba`

Now we are able to access it using the alias URL but we still have links in different places that use "`/content/site/es/test-page`" URL. So we need a redirect rule in place so that all of these pages under `/content/site/es` redirect to their alias URL pages.

How can we achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

We usually implement a solution like this:

- If a page is requested we check in the page component if the requested url is the same as resourceResolver.map(request, path) (this returns a URL with the alias path). If not, we send a permanent redirect to the alias path.
- Links that we generate in our code all get the .map call applied (central utility class or service).
- We also add a link rewriter that checks the same - see https://helpx.adobe.com/experience-manager/using/aem63_link_rewriter.html for a walktrough.

HTH,
Oliver

Comment: i was trying to get 'alias path' of a page and using "resourceResolver.map(request, path) ", it is not returning alias path Ex: alias path - /en/discover-more/alias-landing-blog/page1 actual path- /en/discover-more/blog/page1. resourceResolver.map(request, '/en/discover-more/blog/page1') hasn't given me alias path.